# Is there any software to draw area-proportional Venn diagrams when a∩b∩c= 0?

Tags: data-visualization

I would like to draw area-proportional Venn diagrams with 3 sets of data with any free online software.

I tried with eularAPE software but it doesn't work because my 3-set of data do not overlap. My data are: a =45, b=20, c=12, a∩b =9, a∩c =6, b∩c= 1, a∩b∩c= 0.

Is it possible to generate proportional Venn diagrams when a∩b∩c= 0?

Comment: It is often impossible to draw such a diagram when using circles. Consider, for instance, $|A|=|B|=|C|=2$, $|A\cap B|=|B\cap C|=1$, and $|A\cap B\cap C|=0$. What kinds of shapes do you want to use then?

Comment: I could use ellipses

Comment: That still wouldn't resolve even the simple example I provided, because it would demand that the ellipse for $B$ be partitioned into its intersections with $A$ and $C$, which (for obvious geometric reasons) is not possible when both $A$ and $C$ are also ellipses.

Comment: ok, so is there any type of shape that could adjust to my data?

Comment: Arbitrary (non-convex) shapes would likely be needed. For drawing those with great flexibility and creativity, might I suggest a piece of paper and small box of crayons?  Of course that's out of the question when a lot of data need to be portrayed, but for one-off graphics not only is this approach flexible, fast, and cheap, it also provides a warmth to the resulting graphics that is otherwise difficult to attain with software.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Paper and crayons ready for creative and warmth graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you turn this into a question that could be answered with mosaic plots? See these images for example, same data, different representation. In the mosaic plot area matches the values.

[image: venn diagram][image]

Comment: Nice idea! Could you give an illustration with three, rather than two, events, to show what the result might look like?

Comment: i could give a mosaic plot example, but not the corresponding venn diagram

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Maybe more information is required. I have checked whether the genes affected by drug "a" statistically overlap with genes affected by other five drugs (b, c, d, e and f). Results showed that a only overlap with b and c, although a∩b∩c= 0. I though to represent it by venn diagrams (one with three elements and three with two elements) but I realize that it is not the best way to show these data.

Comment: This is the type of data that my example comes from too, except two genotypes and two analysis methods. Try using a mosaic plot, interweaving a third variable into the horizontal axis. Drug a on the vertical axis, and results from the others on the horizontal.  There is a package called productplots in R that might help. It is not as easy to use as I would like.